# How to display no data found in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In highcharts, if there is no data found in the json value, I want to display an error message.

I used this code:

```
if(options.series[0].data.length == 0) {
    alert('nodatafound');
} else {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

This error appears:

> TypeError: options.series[0].data is undefined

Data from JSON:

```
{
    "chart": {
        "renderTo": "container2",
        "type": "column",
        "marginRight": 10,
        "marginBottom‌": 125
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "",
        "x": -20
    },
    "exporting": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "credits": {
        "enab‌led": false
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "",
        "x": -20
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "labels": {
            "rotation": -90,
            "sty‌le": {
                "fontSize": "10px"
            }
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "plotLines": [{
            "width": 1,
            "c‌olor": "#808080"
        }]
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "shared": true
    },
    "legend": {
        "align": "right",
        "verticalA‌lign": "top",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 20,
        "borderWidth": 0
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": "no‌rmal",
            "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": false,
                "color": "white"
            }
        }
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "2015-16-Q1"
    }, {
        "name": "2015-16-Q2"
    }, {
        "name": "2015-16-Q3"
    }, {
        "na‌me": "2015-16-Q4"
    }]
}
```

Comment: The problem is your `if()` - first check if data even exists: `if(!options.series[0].data || ( options.series[0].data && options.series[0].data.length == 0)) { ... } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [no-data module](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/125-new-features-drilldown-and-no-data) which allows do that.

Ref: `http://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6o8o03fe/1/

Comment: Please update my example with your code, which introduce this issue

Comment: i am getting data from json it sends empty data

Comment: So looks like an issue with json, when you fix that, let me know if problem still appears.